# How to append to a compile time const

Tags: typescript

We have declared as following.

```
type colors = "green" | "blue" | "red";
```

Is there a way we could append to it based on a condition?

Such as:

```
const shouldAppend = // some logic to return true / false.

if (shouldAppend) {
    colors.append('yellow'); // invalid syntax
}
```

Which should update the type to the following.

```
colors = "green" | "blue" | "red" | "yellow";
```

Is it possible to append to a type, and how could I do it?

Comment: Your types must exist at compile time, thus it would be impossible for them to depend on runtime logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in typescript. You are not allowed to mutate types, however you are allowed to create new one:

```js
type Colors = "green" | "blue" | "red";

type NewColors<T extends string> = Colors | T

// Colors | "yellow"
type Result = NewColors<'yellow'>
```

Please keep in mind, that there are two scopes in typescript: `type scope` and `value/runtime scope`. You are not allowed to use types in `runtime scope`. I mean, during compilation all types are removed from source code.

Maybe you should try [rescript](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/extensible-variant), because it allows you to do almost exactly what you want:

```
type t = ..

type t += Other

type t +=
  | Point(float, float)
  | Line(float, float, float, float)
```

It called `Extensible Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `typeof shouldAppend` with a conditional type:

```
const shouldAppend = true;

type Colors =
    | 'red'
    | 'green'
    | 'blue'
    | (typeof shouldAppend extends true ? 'yellow' : never)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWICuAbAJgQQA5YKZjRgF4YoAnJXAbgCgaoBPPGAYRBRDImJpj5gA+MAORlcaYb35DhAczH5J-QSIBGKSkukwAFIzwgAZnESpMOfIVwAPKJe7lKMAPwiGuFBwDuwmAC4YMFwAN1wyAEoaIA)

If you don't need to use the value of `shouldAppend` at runtime, you can make it a type instead of a `const`:

```
type ShouldAppend = true

type Colors =
    | 'red'
    | 'green'
    | 'blue'
    | (ShouldAppend extends true ? 'yellow' : never)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgewK4BsAmBBMkB2aoC8UwATkhAFAWiRQDCCKCJAzoRVJ1AD5QDkJCGj4cuvPgHNBEHCK49+AIxTk5YqAAp4ydFlz4IAD2Ay0bUuSgB+fiAgomAdz5QAXFBwQAbhBIBKCiA)